# Centering ul and take full width of li, while li are aligned to left

Tags: html, css

This is about responsive, so whatever the width of the page it is, the ul should be always centered to the page and li aligned to the left. 
I don't want the ul width to be 100% of the page width, so there should be the same margin at the left and right side of the ul. 
IMPORTANT: The width of ul should be 100% of all the li displayed in one row.

```
<style> 
.box { 
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:black;
    margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


ul {
    background: lightgray;
    overflow: hidden;
}


li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
</ul>
```

There is a little image that should help you understand: [CLICK](http://s28.postimg.org/41m0sh1zh/example.png)

Comment: Pretty sure you will need flexbox or javascript for this. Floats & inline-block can't handle your precise requirement...at least as i understand it.

Comment: I think so.. because I tried every css trick and nothing works.. can you give some resource for what you said? that would be great, thank you!

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I tried with flexbox.. still doesn't work..

Comment: What you want may not be possible without javascript to dynamically adjust the margins.

Comment: I can make it work if I create a media query for each width, but I don't know if this is a good practice. Otherwise I don't have any idea how to do this with js. I will really appreciate if you can give me some resources/tips.

Comment: Well media queries are one answer...most people don't resize browsers so you might be fine. Resources about learning Javascript or Jquery can be found with a simple Google search.